# how to save excel file attached in an email received in a defined sub folder in the inbox of outlook 2007 to a folder on the windows?

Tags: vba, outlook

i need to save the excel attachement received inside outlook messages in a specific sub folder (daily final) located in the inbox and knowing that all the emails in that subflders will be including that excel attached file. i had below an example with excel VBA but it is not working so kindly advie me

```
 Sub SaveAttachmentsToFolder()
 ' This Outlook macro checks a named subfolder in the Outlook Inbox
 ' (here the "daily final" folder) for messages with attached
 ' files of a specific type (here file with an "xls" extension)
 ' and saves them to disk. Saved files are timestamped. The user
 ' can choose to view the saved files in Windows Explorer.
 ' NOTE: make sure the specified subfolder and save folder exist
 ' before running the macro.
 On Error GoTo SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err
 ' Declare variables
 Dim ns As Namespace
 Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
 Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
 Dim Item As Object
 Dim Atmt As Attachment
 Dim FileName As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
 Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("daily final") ' Enter correct subfolder
name.
 i = 0
 ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
 If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
 MsgBox "There are no messages in the Sales Reports folder.",
vbInformation , _
 "Nothing Found"
 Exit Sub
 End If
 ' Check each message for attachments
 For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
 For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
 ' Check filename of each attachment and save if it has "xls" extension
 If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "xls" Then
 ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
 FileName = "C:\Email Attachments\" & _
 Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") &
Atmt.FileName
 Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
 i = i + 1
 End If
 Next Atmt
 Next Item
 ' Show summary message
 If i > 0 Then
 varResponse = MsgBox("I found " & i & " attached files." _
 & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the C:\Email Attachments folder." _
 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to view the files now?" _
 , vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Finished!")
 ' Open Windows Explorer to display saved files if user chooses
 If varResponse = vbYes Then
 Shell "Explorer.exe /e,C:\Email Attachments", vbNormalFocus
 End If
 Else
 MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.",
vbInformation , "Finished!"
 End If
 ' Clear memory
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit:
 Set Atmt = Nothing
 Set Item = Nothing
 Set ns = Nothing
 Exit Sub
 ' Handle Errors
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err:
 MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
 & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
 & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
 & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
 & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
 , vbCritical, "Error!"
 Resume SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit
 End Sub
```

Comment: i need to execute this code in excel VBA and not outlook VBA.

Comment: Please explain "not working". You should include the line that it stops working and any error messages that you receive.

Comment: all the lines in red give a syntax error. thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have cut-and-pasted from a website but you are not familiar with VBA. When you paste code into the VBA Code wondow, it will highlight lines where there are problems. You then apply your knowledge to fix these problems. For example, this line from above should be one statement:

```
MsgBox "There are no messages in the Sales Reports folder.",
vbInformation , _
 "Nothing Found"
```

Like so:

```
MsgBox "Message", buttons, "Title"
```

You can put a statement on three lines like you have it, but you must use the line continuation character (_), you only have one, you need two.

```
MsgBox "There are no messages in the Sales Reports folder.", _
vbInformation , _
 "Nothing Found"
```

Here

```
FileName = "C:\Email Attachments\" & _
 Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") &
```

You have an extra &. A statement cannot end with &

The F1 key can be very helpful in these situations.