# saving excel attachments of outlook messages in a specified folder in windows using outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to save excel file attached in an email received in a defined sub folder in the inbox of outlook 2007 to a folder on the windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293108/how-to-save-excel-file-attached-in-an-email-received-in-a-defined-sub-folder-in)

i really need an outlook vba function to automatically save the excel attachment in a given inbox subfolder called daily and the destination folder of windows has the path C:/daily reports so i appreciate the help and support from your side.

thanks,

Comment: Dear sirs, sorry for disturbance but i will appreciate too much if you can help me in the above issue. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`you can use the below script and run it from rules and alerts from outlook and apply on the needed users or item

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "E:\Attachments\"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

thanks,